# Angularjs module error in jsfiddle but works fine in plnkr

Tags: jsfiddle

Here i have https://jsfiddle.net/1nivas/6g4hxcof/ which is not working
Here is the same angularjs template in https://plnkr.co/edit/u49sV6xhhFOr7bffvLWt?p=preview which is working fine.
Can you look at and tell me whats wrong. I would like to use jsfiddle because its looks nice. I never used jsfiddle before

```js
// the main (app) module
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

// add a controller
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "hello world";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{msg}}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include AngularJS 1.4.8 in you fiddle

[snapshot attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I51EY.png)

Comment: Thanks. do you know whats the difference between no wrap - in <head>: and no wrap - in <body>: where it will effect? and how to add custom angular version?

Comment: no wrap in <head> : javascipt code placed in head section. no wrap in <body> : javascipt code placed in body section